# Override DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using `Datetime.Minvalue` which return 1.1.0001. This value can not be stored to DB because year is smaller than 1975.

Is it possible to override `DateTime.Minvalue` to 1.1.1901?

Regards

Comment: What database are you using and what field type are you trying to store the value in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. You could instead use [SqlDateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx) (1753-01-01), define your own constant for 1901-01-01 if that's what you want to use, or actually use a nullable DateTime:

```
DateTime? dateVal = null;
```

In the instance where no date is specified, a null may make more sense and persist DBNull.Value to the database instead of a "special" value like you're currently doing.

Or, as a final option....at the point you come to persist to the database, do a check for DateTime.MinValue and switch in an alternative. But I'd recommend the nullable DateTime.

Comment: Yes, it is. Check Nbuilder's issue list. Trying to find how they've stomped on the CLR O_o.

Comment: Why on earth did I get a downvote for correcting an error on an outdated question? You can absolutely override anything.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible.  Everybody who finds this code will hate you.  Some will likely harm you.

```
typeof(DateTime)
    .GetField ("MinValue")
    .SetValue (typeof(DateTime), new DateTime(1901, 1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using a method for this

```
DateTime GetMinDateTime()
{
   return DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(900);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nullable  DateTime for such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a static field, and those can't be overridden.

You will need to write a Guard or conversion of some sort

Answer (score 0):

No. Since DateTime.MinValue is a static, there is no simple means to override. I would suggest replacing DateTime.MinValue with a constant, or in your data access code, convert DateTime values equal to DateTime.MinValue to 1900-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only coding for Microsoft SQL Server you can substitue System.DateTime for System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime. If I have understood correctly, the System.Data.SqlTypes data types are directly compatible with the database data types, which avoids the situation you encountered.